# Upgrading driver of a usb 3.0 ss to usb 3.1

Tags: usb, usb-3

This may seem odd but I was wondering if it was possible to upgrade the driver for a usb 3.0 SS controller to a usb 3.1.  As far as I can tell there isn't much of a difference between the ports for 3.0 type A and 3.1 type A.  There is probably hardware limitations but I was wondering if it was possible.

Comment: No;  It is not possible.

Comment: Why is it not possible?

Comment: Because the controller is a 3.0 controller not 3.1, there are some huge differences, even if you some how did manage to do it, it wouldn't change the speed of the port you do understand that right